# Disable a single column dragging in JTable

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtable

How should I disable just a single column from dragging in JTable? I want to allow other columns from dragging but just the first column (indexed at 0). Thanks.

Comment: Why not having a look at my solution here?
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/23829245/458157][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23829245/458157

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to create your own `TableColumnModel` (extend [DefaultTableColumnModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableColumnModel.html)) and to override [`moveColumn`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html#moveColumn%28int,%20int%29) to only call `super.moveColumn` when the column is allowed to be dragged.

**EDIT**: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155137/how-to-keep-a-single-column-from-being-reordered-in-a-jtable/1155277#1155277) first.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite on point for you ....found on another blog

```
yourJTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false)
```

this gets the entire table not to reorder columns which is what I needed.  Exploring the Override is the correct route