# Sort JTable when mouse released

Tags: java, swing, events, sorting, jtable

I have a JTable with property AutoCreateRowSorter set to true. It works fine on click, but if I move mouse during click just for 1px, sorting does not appear, which is uncomfortable in some situations.  How to fix this?

UPD I just want sorting to appear when mouse released.

Comment: [never saw that can you please to test with](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12271011/714968)

Comment: Do you mean that dragging the mouse starts to drag the column?

Comment: @trashgod I meant situation when you move mouse on some rough surface. Columns are not dragged, just no sorting applies.

Comment: The component thinks you want to drag the column; it just hasn't started to animate the drag. The delay varies by platform. You might look at how to [disable dragging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2104228/230513).

Comment: @mKorbel how can I apply default sorting when mouse released?

Comment: @trashgod I've this written: devicesTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false) and devicesTable.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false)

Comment: by default, sorting is triggered on mouseClicked (most probably platform/LAF dependent as well). No way except extreme hacking to hook into that.

Comment: post an SSCCE, with hardcoded value for JTable, see that about 30-50 codelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty (read: *don't if you aren't absolutely desperate and know exactly what you doing!*) approach is to hook into the MouseListener installed by the uiDelegate and move the sort trigger into the released method. This involves

- a custom MouseListener which delegates all events except the clicked to the originally installed and sorts before passing on the released
- replace the original with the custom
- update the replacement whenever the LAF is changed (because the original is controlled by the ui). This requires subclassing of JTableHeader and do the wiring in updateUI

The custom listener:

```
public static class EventHook implements MouseListener {

    private JTableHeader header;
    private MouseListener delegate;

    public EventHook(JTableHeader header) {
        this.header = header;
        installHook();
    }

    protected void installHook() {
        MouseListener[] listeners = header.getMouseListeners();
        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
            MouseListener l = listeners[i];
            if (l.getClass().getName().contains("TableHeaderUI")) {
                this.delegate = l;
                listeners[i] = this;
            }
            header.removeMouseListener(l);
        }
        for (MouseListener l : listeners) {
            header.addMouseListener(l);
        }
    }

    public void uninstallHook() {
        MouseListener[] listeners = header.getMouseListeners();
        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
            MouseListener l = listeners[i];
            if (l == this) {
                listeners[i] = delegate;
            }
            header.removeMouseListener(l);
        }
        for (MouseListener l : listeners) {
            header.addMouseListener(l);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // sort before calling super
        sort(e);
        delegate.mouseReleased(e);
    }

    private void sort(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!header.isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }
        // do nothing if dragged
        if (header.getDraggedDistance() != 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (e.getClickCount() % 2 == 1 &&
                SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
            JTable table = header.getTable();
            RowSorter sorter;
            if (table != null && (sorter = table.getRowSorter()) != null) {
                int columnIndex = header.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if (columnIndex != -1) {
                    columnIndex = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(
                            columnIndex);
                    sorter.toggleSortOrder(columnIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // swallow the clicked - want to trigger sort on released
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        delegate.mousePressed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        delegate.mouseEntered(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        delegate.mouseExited(e);
    }

}
```

The subclassed JTableHeader

```
public static class MyTableHeader extends JTableHeader {
    private EventHook hook;
    public MyTableHeader(TableColumnModel model) {
        super(model);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateUI() {
        if (hook != null) {
            hook.uninstallHook();
            hook = null;
        }
        super.updateUI();
        hook = new EventHook(this);
    }

}
```

Usage, either subclass JTable and override createDefaultTableHeader or manually set the header:

```
// either subclass
JTable table = new JTable(new AncientSwingTeam()) {

    @Override
    protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {
        return new MyTableHeader(getColumnModel());
    }

};
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll take it into consideration. I'm not sure my problem is enough important to make so great changes.