# Prevent first column from reordering in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep a single column from being reordered in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155137/how-to-keep-a-single-column-from-being-reordered-in-a-jtable)

Using:

```
getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
```

Will prevent ALL columns from re-ordering. However, I wish to only prevent the first column from being reordered.

After googling this is the closest I have found:

```
setColumnModel(new DefaultTableColumnModel() {  
    public void moveColumn(int columnIndex, int newIndex) {  
        if (columnIndex == 0 || newIndex == 0) return; // don't allow  
        super.moveColumn(columnIndex, newIndex);  
    }  
});
```

However, this causes a strange visual flaw when attempting to drag the first column. Any one has a perfect solution to this problem?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Also see [How to keep a single column from being reordered in a JTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1155137/1048330)

Comment: fyi: added yet another suboptimal approach to the other answer, dirty but no visual glitch :-)