# JTable, disable user column dragging

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have declared my `JTable` as:

```
data_table = new JTable(info, header) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

But I've seen that at runtime it's possible to **drag the columns** with mouse.
How can I disable that?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

`data_table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);` should do the job, unless you mean that the user can resize column headers.

Comment: Also nice readings here : http://www.coderanch.com/t/346302/GUI/java/Restrict-User-Move-Column-JTable And another answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155137/how-to-keep-a-single-column-from-being-reordered-in-a-jtable

Answer (score -1):

To anyone having this problem using **Netbeans** IDE you can disable the user from dragging columns in the JTable by doing the following steps.

[image: Customizer Dialog]

- Right click the table
- Select Table contents
- Click the columns tab
- Uncheck the Allow to reorder columns by drag and drop